# Add new parameter to $resource after using ngChange, Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I am having trouble trying to append a new url parameter after selecting a genre to create a request to the API.

My `ng-change` is `genreChange`. When it been selected, it should automatically append the new url parameter like this `&with_genre=fiction` in the `$scope.movies` url before submitting  the form with `submitButton`

```
<form ng-submit="submitButton()" name="cForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <h2>Discover the gems</h2>       
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="genreSelect" ng-change="genreChange()">
                <option ng-repeat="genre in genreList.genres" value="{{genre.id}}">{{genre.name}}</option>
             </select>    
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="hello" />           
</form>
```

-

```
$scope.genreChange = function() {
    $scope.genreVar =  $scope.genreSelect;
    $scope.movies.get({with_genres: $scope.genreVar});
}

$scope.movies = $resource('http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie:action', {
    api_key: apikey,
    callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
}, {
    get: {
        method: 'JSONP'
    }
});

$scope.submitButton = function() {
    $scope.films = $scope.movies.get();
}
```

I am doing this method just in case a user leaves it blank.

Thanks

Comment: Do you do it for `put` or `get`. And what problem are you having?

Comment: Actually `get`, just need to add new url parameter

Comment: It same as you do for put `$scope.movies.get({with_genres: $scope.genreVar});`. Is it not working?

Comment: I checked the Net console, it works but the submitButton() overrides it. Which means two calls are made, it should be one

Comment: You should not make the call when calling `genreChange` method. Just store the param that you need to pass in a scope variable. Then pass it in the get method.

Comment: That is exactly what I did earlier, but if the user ignore this selection, the param `with_genres=` with blank value will return with an error.

Comment: You can check that with if condition in submitButton.

Comment: Made a breakthrough, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what Resource.bind does.

```
var MovieResource = $resource('http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie:action', {
    api_key: apikey,
    callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
}, {
    get: {
        method: 'JSONP'
    }
});

$scope.movies = MovieResource;

$scope.genreChange = function() {
    $scope.genreVar =  $scope.genreSelect;
    $scope.movies = MovieResource.bind({with_genres: $scope.genreVar})
}

$scope.submitButton = function() {
    $scope.films = $scope.movies.get();
}
```